# R - checking HTML for formatting tags (bold, italics etc.)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, edgar, sec

I am using edgarWebR to parse 10K (SEC EDGAR) filings. I am trying to write an algorithm to deduce whether each HTML element is normal text, a subheading or a heading by checking how the document is formatted (e.g. some 10Ks might have all headings in bold italics, and subheadings in just italics)

edgarWebR returns a dataframe with each element corresponding to a row, containing the text and html. An example of some html:

`<p style="margin-top:18px;margin-bottom:0px"><font style="font-family:ARIAL" size="2"><b><i>Our quarterly operating results have fluctuated in the past and might continue to fluctuate, causing the value of our common stock to decline substantially. </i></b></font></p>`

As we can see, the above should be flagged as bold and italic. However, this is represented differently in different filings. For example, this filing uses `<b>` to denote bold, whereas some say something like font-weight = bold.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is there an R package that will parse the HTML and either tell me that it is bold and italic, or return a list of tags which are specifically formatting tags (not span, p etc).

Alternatively, how can i check each row against a manually compiled list of indicators of bold and italic ("bold", `<b>`, strong) and have it return any elements of the list which are matched for each row?

At the end, I plan to tabulate values to determine heading levels. E.g. if I count 100 elements with neither bold nor italic, 20 elements with just `<b>`, and 10 elements containing `<b>` and "Italic", I can deduce that bold and italic represents headings for this particular filing, and bold alone denotes subheadings.

Comment: In general, regular expressions can be used to detect something like this. And also, in general, using regular expressions to parse more complicated HTML is a liability. If all you need to do is determine if a sentence includes one of a couple of bold tags, then that should be controllable. With your sample sentence above, are you just looking for a true/false return? (same for italic). It might be as easy as `grepl("<b>|font-weight\\s*=\\s*bold", x, ignore.case=TRUE)` (and similar for italics).

Answer (score 1):

I think all you're looking for is if a particular string contains html markup that indicates something in that string should be bold and/or italics.

```r
S <- '<p style="margin-top:18px;margin-bottom:0px"><font style="font-family:ARIAL" size="2"><b><i>Our quarterly operating results have fluctuated in the past and might continue to fluctuate, causing the value of our common stock to decline substantially. </i></b></font></p>'
grepl("<b>|<font-weight\\s*=\\s*bold", S, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
grepl("<i>|<font-style\\s*=\\s*italic", S, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is this close, @ks123321?

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your answer. I was leaning towards something like your answer -  `mutate(is_bold = if_else(grepl("<b>|<strong>|weight: bold|weight:bold",raw,ignore.case = TRUE), 'bold', '')) %>% 
    mutate(is_italic = if_else(grepl("<i>|<em>|style: italic|style:italic",raw,ignore.case = TRUE), 'italic', ''))` . However, since I am planning to apply this to thousands of heterogeneously formatted filings, whether I could expand to more than just bold and italics - an actual HTML parser to extract formatting tags might be more robust than just considering bold and italics.

Comment: I am concerned that some filings may use different formatting techniques than just bold and italics, which my algorithm would miss. Also, do you know of any other ways that bolds or italics can be represented in HTML? So far for bold I've got <b>, <strong> and weight:bold. For italic I've got <i>,<em> and style: italic. Thanks again for your ideas.

Comment: That's fine, though good luck: regex to parse HTML is fraught with many problems. You should really use a parser specific to html. Unfortunately, I don't have any advice on that at the moment. Good luck!