# All the ways of representing bold and italics in HTML?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to process 10K filings by using the HTML styles to deduce the heading levels of each element of HTML. I have asked about my broader project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981247/r-checking-html-for-formatting-tags-bold-italics-etc)

I didn't get many answers, perhaps because my question was too broad, so with this post, I am asking more specifically about HTML. What are all the different ways of representing bold and italics (I am planning to manually feed in a list of possible indicators of bold and italic to check the element). So far I've got:

- Bold: `<b>`, `<strong>`, `weight:bold`
- Italic: `<i>`, `<em>`, `style:italic`

Thank you

Comment: This entirely depends on your specific issue. There are too many ways to make bold/italic text with HTML/CSS/JS to give you a useful answer.

Comment: How about the element has `class="someA someB someC someD someE"` (etc) with any of those classes specifying bold and/or italic, possibly even overriding one another, and there could be also be some with `!important` tacked onto them.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of that. I am looking at html of this kind: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1640201/000110465916107115/a16-6863_110k.htm and had only come across the ways I listed in my post in the 20 filings or so that I checked, but there are thousands of them I need to process.

Comment: impossible to detect when they use a stylesheet other than manually checking for an element and checking its computed style

Comment: Thanks @epascarello . So does that mean that in cases where the authors have used a style sheet, it is very difficult to check how different elements appear? I ask because it seems to be the only way to distinguish between different heading levels with these filings - there are no other consistent tags of any kind.

Comment: There is no easy check. You would have to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle and figure out what they are doing.

Comment: I see. If I narrow the scope of my question to just the HTML tags within elements for filings without a style sheet, am I missing any from my list? I may, for now, omit those with a style sheet.